# mod_rewrite rules not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to do this with mod_rewrite .htaccess:

```
myurl.com/category/sub/title + optionally (/en-GB for language)
myurl.com/category/ID (number)
myurl.com/content/title (Letters with - & _)
```

/sub can be optionally

with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ index.php?page=$1&sub_page=$2&tree_page=$3 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Sometimes a URL does not have the subcategory and is only the category.

However, the first code is not working. How do I achieve it for all the 3 options above?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to construct a complex regex that accepts all that, go with more specialized rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L, QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ index.php?page=$1&sub_page=$2 [L, QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ index.php?page=$1&sub_page=$2&tree_page=$3 [L, QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Note that I have not tested this. It is only meant to point you into the right direction...